# Log to text file - items in Progress Tab of SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, package

In SSIS, i need to write into a log, whatever items get displayed on the **Progress** tab. Is there an inbuilt feature to do this? i tried the **logging** option but it logs too many details and the log is pretty huge for a single package run.

i need only whatever gets logged on the Progress tab to be logged on to a text file when the package undergoes a scheduled run through **Sql server agent**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

> You have an option at DTEXEC at the command-line. There is a switch called /Reporting or /Rep for short.

I found it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/441775/Fetching-Progress-tab-result-in-text-file-in-SSIS)

This [link](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/48334) says the same.

This is your [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/767f94d7-933e-4858-945b-c84a6e9ce2e7/capturing-execution-results?forum=sqlintegrationservices) in MSDN. Its pretty useless since they suggest you turn on logging, which you've already done. I thought I should add it anyways for completeness.

Comment: i tried the /Rep switch . @command=N'/FILE "\"C:\path\file.dtsx\"" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REP  P > "C:\Users\SQLSERVERAGENT\DIJobLogFiles\Progress\DataImportDI.log"',

Comment: Option ">" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not sure. It looks like your file path for the log file might be the culprit. I'd try a simple path and a .txt file to see if thats the problem. If thats not it, i'm at a loss